# jdbc + large postgresql query give out of memory

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a postgresql query which returns a large result:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
st = connection.createStatement(
  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,
  ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY
);
st.setFetchSize(100);
logMemory();
System.out.println("start query ");
rs = st.executeQuery(queryString);
System.out.println("done query ");
logMemory();
```

but this uses a lot of memory:

```
Free memory; 4094347680  (= 3905 mb).
start query 
done query
Free memory; 2051038576  (= 1956 mb).
```

(printed with Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() )

So far it works but the database is going to be a lot bigger. I don't ever need the entire result in memory; I just need to proccess each row, write the results to disk and go to the next row.

I know 'setFetchSize' is only a hint, but I would find it strange if postgresql/jdbc would ignore it, as it's around for ages.

Any way to get around this? My only idea so far is to make a batch script which streams the result of the query to disk and then parse the file from Java...

Comment: Just curious, what is the max heap size you are running with? Or are you using default?

Comment: It's -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M, it's a vista 8GB machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ouch, this is one of the most nasty bugs using JDBC I've seen. You should change

```
st = connection.createStatement(
  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,
  ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY
);
```

into

```
st = connection.createStatement(
  ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
);
```

Maybe simply

```
st = connection.createStatement();
```

will work as well (as you've met the other criteria for a cursor).

Comment: what's the bug? is it a real memory leak or is something else going on? Do you think it's postgres only?

Comment: @rogerdpack OP changed the method parameters for `createStatement`. Both parameters are 'int'-s but means some different things. So it is not any bug in the JDBC implementation.

Answer (score 13):

[Here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/query.html#query-with-cursor) are the guidelines for ensuring that the result set is actually retrieved with a cursor. You seem to hit on all of the known ones in your code, but you haven't specified the statement, so it may be several strung together with semicolons (unlikely, by the looks of your code). You have to be using the V3 protocol (version 7.4 or later). Do all of these things apply to your case?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried switching on/off all the guidelines. The statement is simply 

 Select hh.data, hh.customer_ID 
 from dataTable hh 
 join customer PH on hh.customer_ID = PH.customer_ID  ;

and it's postgresql 8.3 and I'm using postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc4.jar .

Comment: I'm stumped. I'd say the next best step is to post on groups that focus on Postgresql. There are probably some other non-obvious things that causes/can force the connection to use a cursor. I'd crack open the JDBC source code (that is the nice thing about open source) and see what is going on in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I was struggling this problem for the whole day, until I've found a requirement for `conn.setAutoCommit(false)` on the page you cited.